# Passing/exposing T on a ServiceStack request filter

Tags: c#, generics, annotations, servicestack, action-filter

I've got a request attribute that I'm decorating some services, but I need to pass a generic type into it because of some logic happening inside of it. It looks like so:

```
[SomeAttribute(typeof(MyClass))]
```

This works well, but if I do something such as...

```
[SomeAttribute<MyClass>]
```

... I'll get an *"Annotations cannot be generic"* compile-time error.

Inside my attribute execute logic, I need to do the following:

```
someClass.doSomething<MyClass>(someString);
```

So, my question is...

- Can I cast `MyClass` to some form of `T` so I can use it that way?
- Is there another way I can pass `T` in the attribute without getting a compile error?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error messages says .NET Annotations can't be generic so you can only pass in a late-bound `Type`. The only way to call a generic method from a late-bound Type is to use reflection, e.g:

```
var mi = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("doSomething");
var genericMi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(MyAttributeType));
var doSomethingFn = (Func<string, object>) genericMi.CreateDelegate(
  typeof(Func<string, object>));
```

Then you can cache and call the compiled delegate of the generic method which takes a `string` and returns an `object`, e.g:

```
object response = doSomethingFn(someString);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, @mythz! So, I see where you're going... and it makes pretty good sense. Your example, however, throws a runtime exception of "method arguments are incompatible" on `doSomethingFn`.

Comment: P.S.: Since you're behind ServiceStack, here's a bit more context... I'm trying to implement caching over an attribute, `this.cache.Get<T>("key")` is where I'm trying to get to. Oh, and using Mono, FYI...

Makes sense? And thanks again!

Comment: @napo It needs to call a wrapper method that returns an `object` instead of the generic `T` response, have a look at [ServiceGatewayExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/f4c9606b17dae06c7af193d7661dfa2b31d8b722/src/ServiceStack.Client/ServiceGatewayExtensions.cs#L30) which is essentially doing the same thing. This works exactly the same way in Mono. Otherwise you can call it with reflection directly, i.e. without caching the delegate, e.g: `genericMi.Invoke(this.cache, new[]{ someString })`.

Comment: Your latter solution works wonders, @mythz! You rock! I'm looking at the former as well in a bit more detail, since caching the delegate would certainly be icing on the cake. Thanks so much again!